# What is krb5-locales?

Tags: locale

How localization krb5 for ubuntu? In package krb5-locales only one mo files for en_US.

I want use message with change password on russian:

- Enter It Again

and etc.

Create mit-krb.mo in locales. With kdestory all work, but login with ligthdm, unity-greeter and pam-krb5 not!

[kdestroy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRLPa.jpg)
[lightdm+unity-greeter+pam_krb5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXauh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

"Kerberos" is a computer network authentication protocol and "krb5-locales" are the settings related to [internationalization](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/krb5-locales). Or as explained in the link:

> **Internationalization support for MIT Kerberos**
>
> Kerberos is a system for authenticating users and services on a network.
>    Kerberos is a trusted third-party service. That means that there is a
>    third party (the Kerberos server) that is trusted by all the entities on
>    the network (users and services, usually called "principals").
>
> This is the MIT reference implementation of Kerberos V5.
>
> This package contains internationalized messages for MIT Kerberos.

---

So ... any text used in "kerberos" is stored in "krb5-locales" and based on you language settings it will pick up the translation for your language (if available).

---

It is 3rd party software so I assume translation are done by them.

Comment: I took a look at the package. It's empty (besides some doc files), so I understand the OP's confusion.

Comment: weird. It should have them all I would assume. I have seen Kerberos in dutch D:

Comment: Please upload for example your MO files mit-krb5